# Html5 offline manifest Not working

Tags: html, file, manifest, offline-caching

I am testing the offline functionality provided by Html5 manifest file. I am working with xamp
and I have 3 files :

1. index.html
2. offline.html
3. blank.jpg

What I want is that when I am offline and try to load index.html the offline.html should be displayed.

This is the manifest file :

```
> 

CACHE MANIFEST

# This is a comment

CACHE:
blank.jpg

FALLBACK:
/ /offline.html

NETWORK:
*
```

What am I doing wrong?